# How to stop execution of current event handler thread when subsequent events simultaneously call the same handler?

Tags: javascript, events, jquery

- I have an input text which is used to filter and sort the contents of a select dropdown.
- The filtration/selection function `filterSort()` is called on `keyup` on the input text.

**Code**

```
$(inputTextField).keyup(function() 
{
     //lot of logic to filter the options of a select dropdown and sort them based on the text of inputTextField


});
```

**Problem**
 The filtration/sorting logic is working fine now. But I realized that while a user is typing,  there are multiple threads executing the code inside `filterSort()`. So, I want to stop execution of the code inside the `keyup()` if another `keyup()` has happened, because there is no need to continue with an older thread as its results will be anyway discarded. Never encountered such a situation. How do I do this?

I am not yet sure if that is functionally causing any problem, I think I am getting the correct filtered+sorted results in the end.

Comment: you mean to interrupt already fired event ?

Comment: yes... stop execution of an already fired keyup event, when a new keyup is fired. Note that the latter keyup has to execute completely, unless another keyup does not happen later.

Comment: i think it not possible, may be better to make queue of events using once()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to delay the filtering operation with [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setTimeout) and reset the timer every time the user presses a key. jQuery's [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method can be used to keep track of the timer identifier:

```
$(inputTextField).keyup(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var timer = $this.data("timer");
    if (timer) {
        window.clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    $this.data("timer", window.setTimeout(function() {
        // Lots of logic to filter and sort the options...
    }, 250));
});
```